# HTML Filter using search and multi select (swatches)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been searching on net to find the filtration of search(text field) and multi-select (swatches) but couldn't find any way out.

I want to make both work as an intersection. e.g

I have a list :-

- Banana (fruit)
- Orange (fruit)
- Carrot (vegetable)
- Tomato (vegetable)
- Rajma (beans)

select text field ( Orange ) 
multiselect ( Fruit  Vegetable  Beans )

Now, when I search "orange" then It should return orange and when I click on vegetable then "no result"

also, when I select fruit and vegetable then text field should only search in "banana, tomato, carrot and orange"

Both the filters work simultaneously.

Please help me put in this problem.

Thanks

Comment: For this you have to use php or whatever language you want with condition and sql query..it just depend on your requirement with particular platform.

Comment: Can you include `html` tried at Question?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote [some code](https://jsfiddle.net/wawoaptu/) (JSFiddle) with simple functionality. Take note, that since I am not using a database or anything of the sort, filtering the elements looks through them all, whereas a database query would only get you the needed elements.
Feel free to customize the code. If you want the single-select field to update too, you should implement the according function - `function updateSingleSelect(){}`. I added it, but haven't implemented it. You can deduce the logic from my search function.
I am using objects `{name: 'orange', subclass: 'fruit'}` as the items for search.